# How to add a gap between the nvd3 legend and the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, nvd3.js

I'm aware that this question might have be asked before, and as i tried looking to get the answer for this issue, i haven't really found one. Similar to the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/51/, im trying to add gap between legend and chart by doing:

```
  graph.select(".nv-wrap.nv-legendWrap nv-legend nv-series").attr("transform", "translate(100,75)").style('padding','200px');
  graph.select(".nv-wrap.nv-lineChart").attr("transform", "translate(100,75)");
```

With this approach im able to move the position of the chart, however when i click on one of the legend( turn on/off circle), the chart goes back to its original position. i also tried:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart().options({
                width: 1050
            }).margin({top: 0, right:30, left:80, bottom: 150});
```

but no luck.. any ideas on how this one can be solved?? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try like below:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart()
chart.legend.margin({top: 0, right:30, left:80, bottom: 150});
```

[Updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfe2B/106/)

Hope it helps:)