# How can I move controls and legend in nvd3.js multibar chart?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3.js to generate a multibar chart, I've been trying to move controls (Grouped and Stacked) and legend to avoid overlap between them.

Comment: Select the respective container elements and set the new positions on them.

Comment: you can move legend like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553142/how-to-add-a-gap-between-the-nvd3-legend-and-the-chart